# could .bash_profile, in theory, be slammed into the iCloud Drive and symlinked?

Tags: icloud, bash

could .bash_profile in theory be slammed onto iCloud Drive and symlinked from there? I'd love to use the same .bash_profile on every computar.

Why this isn't the same as Dropbox - this, if answered, would allow for a person to install a new computer, run a command (doing a symlink to .bash_profile from a specific place on the iCloud Drive), and have all their aliases + etc  without having to install a separate application like Dropbox.

Comment: Generally speaking, the solution is the same for Dropbox and iCloud Drive (and for Google Drive etc.). Symlinking `.bash_profile` directly is proposed in one of the comments to the question, the answers provide additional ways of implementing it. If these solutions don't work for you, please be more specific in explaining why you don't consider your question to be a duplicate.